Java Spring Data JPA: Why are payments not fetched when updating student's due status after payment creation?
Student and Payment entity, having OneToMany relationship.
So, the problem is, initially, I am trying to save the payment with the student (createPayment), which is working fine. However, in the updateIsDue method, when I retrieve the student using studentService.getStudent(studentID), the student object has an empty list of payments ([]). In the previous method, I have successfully saved the payment, and it is also saved in the database. This is the issue: why is the payments data not fetching?
@PostMapping("/payment/{studentID}")
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<PaymentDTO> pay(@RequestBody PaymentDTO paymentdto, @PathVariable String studentID){
    PaymentDTO paid = paymnetService.createPayment(paymentdto,Integer.parseInt(studentID));
    paymnetService.updateIsDue(Integer.parseInt(studentID));
    return new ResponseEntity<PaymentDTO>(paid, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Override
public PaymentDTO createPayment(PaymentDTO paymentdto, int studentID) {
    try {
        Student student = studentService.getStudent(studentID);
        Payment payment = modelMapper.map(paymentdto, Payment.class);
        payment.setStudent(student);
        payment.setPaymentStatus(true);
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy-MM-dd");
        String paymentDate = today.format(formatter);
        payment.setPaymentDate(paymentDate);
        Payment savedPayment = paymentrepo.save(payment);
        return modelMapper.map(savedPayment, PaymentDTO.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log the exception or handle it as required
        System.out.println("An error occurred while creating payment: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        // You might want to throw a custom exception or return a meaningful response
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create payment. Please try again later.");
    }
}




public void updateIsDue(int studentID) {
    Student student = studentService.getStudent(studentID);
    if (student == null) {
        System.out.println("Student not found with ID: " + studentID);
        return;
    }

    try {
        StudentDTO studentdto = modelMapper.map(student, StudentDTO.class);

        boolean isDue = rentPaymentSchedule.isPaymentDue(studentdto);
        boolean isPaid = rentPaymentSchedule.isPaymentMade(studentdto);

        if (isDue && !isPaid) {
            // Payment is due and not paid
            student.setPaymentDue(true);
        } else if (isPaid) {
            student.setPaymentDue(false);
            Student updatedStudent = rentPaymentSchedule.updateDueDate(student); // Update due date for next month
            studentService.saveStudentFromPaymentServiceImpl(updatedStudent);
            return;
        }

        studentService.saveStudentFromPaymentServiceImpl(student);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error occurred while mapping student information: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

In the Student entity, I am using EAGER fetching to get payments. Additionally, I have tested studentService.getStudent(studentID) from a separate controller, and it is returning the proper response with the payments.
I am unable to understand the issue. What is happening here?
